# No sound coming from embed YouTube video

Tags: ios, video, swift2

When I run the following code in my iOS simulator I get sound from the embed YouTube video.  When I run this on my iPhone 6 I get no sound coming from the speakers but I do get sound from the headphones. Is this a hardware issue or is it software?

```
import UIKit

class ThreeKeyViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let youTubeUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/hP-vuMaoHjU"
    videoView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in


        self.videoView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(self.videoView.frame.width)\" height=\"\(self.videoView.frame.height)\" src=\"\(youTubeUrl)\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)

        print("This is run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block")
    })
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SWIFT 2.0 version I have the same problem for me the solution was to add in the AppDelegate. Thanks to Daleks. Must not forget to Import AVFoundation.

```
Import UIKit
import AVFoundation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)  
    }
    return true
}enter code here
```